# React state is array of objects which are react elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm running into an issue right now trying to render a list using react, where I'm saving my react elements into the state, but the problem I'm getting is that the console outputs this:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Here is what the state looks like which causes the error:
[image]

```js
export default class UserData extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      resultsItems: {}
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {

    fetch(url)
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      }).then(data => {
        console.log(data.items);
        let items = data.items.map((item) => {
          console.log(item.title);
          return (
            <li>
              <h2>item.title</h2>
            </li>
          )
        });

        this.setState({resultsItems: items});
        console.log("state", this.state.resultsItems);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.updateLoginStatus(false)}>
          Logout
        </button>
        <div>
          ID: {this.props.user}
          {this.state.resultsItems}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition to Chris' correct answer, note that `item.title` needs curly braces in your `componentDidMount`.

Comment: As an aside, I would very strongly encourage you to avoid storing your components themselves in state, and to instead store the serializable data needed to _build_ the components. See [the official advice on the matter](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state) for more detail

Comment: @Hamms very true.

Comment: While it was asked after, the answers are more complete here: [Add element to a state React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875097/add-element-to-a-state-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By way of demonstrating the sort of thing [Hamms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1810460/hamms) is talking about in their comment:

```
class UserData extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      resultsItems: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    // Simulate API response
    const resultsItems = [
      { title: 'foo' },
      { title: 'bar' },
      { title: 'wombat' }
    ]
    this.setState({ resultsItems })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.resultsItems.map(item => <ResultsItem item={item} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function ResultsItem ({ item }) {
  return <li>{item.title}</li>
}
```

However, [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2030321/chris)' answer is correct as to the cause of the error message: the first render tries to use an empty object and not an array, which fails.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are correctly setting an array to your state on `componentDidMount`, however the *initial state* in your constructor is an object and not an array!

So change this:

```
this.state = {
  resultsItems: {}
}
```

to this:

```
this.state = {
  resultsItems: []
}
```

Comment: this didn't seem to work. It seems the return statement from inside of the `fetch` is adding objects to that array, which is causing the issue.

Comment: @KeyferMathewson, you might have to double-check what your fetch actually returns. There is no way atm for us to see what your API returns.