# React Hooks: Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to update an object created with React.createElement(). The property I am trying to update is `particleCopy.props.style.top`. Below is my code.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Particles.scss';

export default function Particles() {
  const particleStyle = { color: 'blue', position: 'absolute', top: '0px' };
  const [particle, setParticle] = useState(
    React.createElement('div', { style: particleStyle }, '*')
  );

  const moveParticleDown = (particle, top) => {
    const particleCopy = Object.assign({}, particle);
    particleCopy.props.style.top = top + 'px';
    setParticle(particleCopy);
  };

  return (
    <div className="particles_container">
      <div className="particles">{particle}</div>
      <div className="controls">
        <button onClick={() => moveParticleDown(particle, 10)}>down</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am getting the following error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'top' of object '#<Object>'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `particleCopy` function is only creating a shallow copy of `particle`, meaning you're trying to mutate the object `particle` is pointing to. You can either look into a deep cloning library or, what seems more idiomatic in React these days, to spread the object down as far as you have to:

```
const particleCopy = {
  ...particle,
  props: {
    ...particle.props,
    style: {
      ...particle.props.style,
      top: top + 'px'
    }
  }
}
setParticle(particleCopy);
```

Comment: thanks it works, so I guess this is more of a javascript error, not so much react then?

Comment: Yeah, the issue is really that Object.assign doesn't clone an object more than one level. I guess technically this issue is associated with React because React deep freezes stateful objects so you can't accidentally mutate them.

Answer (score 3):

I actually scoured the internet if it's recommendable if you should add elements in state. I don't think this is how you should implement that behavior in React. Well, if it works, I'll keep an open mind. Found another question that tackles this discussion (check 2nd comment): [Add element to a state React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875097/add-element-to-a-state-react)

Not to mention doing a copy, can be costly.

Why not save the position as state?

```
export default function Particles() {
  const particleStyle = { color: 'blue', position: 'absolute', top: '0px' };
  // if ever you need to track other than top
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0});

  const moveParticleDown = p => {
    setPosition({top: p});
  };

  return (
    <div className="particles_container">
      <div className="particles">
        <div style={...particleStyle, top: `${position.top}px`} /> 
      </div>
      <div className="controls">
        <button onClick={() => moveParticleDown(10)}>down</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```