# Cannot assign to read only property of #<Object> using React with Recoil

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, assign

I'm trying to update my state (an array of objects), but get the above error whenever I try to use .map or edit a clone of the state object.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
setUserMeasurements((oldUserMeasurements) => {
  return oldUserMeasurements.map(nameAndMeasure => {
    if (nameAndMeasure.name === name) { nameAndMeasure.measure = 60 }
    return nameAndMeasure;
  })
})
```

})

It doesn't seem to like it when I try the "nameAndMeasure.measure = 60" section of code, but I can't understand why. Can anyone explain?

Comment: I think it might have something to do with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478289/react-hooks-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property

But the solution looks unusually complicated for what I would guess is a common issue?

Comment: You're still mutating the original state, you might want to try and just `return nameAndMeasure.name === name ? {...nameAndMeasure, measure: 60} : nameAndMeasure`, this way you're not mutating the object, but rather creating a _new_ object, and overwriting the `measure` property of the new object if needed

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons . I'm confused as I thought when we use .map it creates a new array - in which case I wouldn't be changing the original state would I? I've had a look at the .map documentation but can't see anything. It says something about forEach or using a for/of loop - would they have solved it do you think?

Comment: Oh, also @NickParsons - using the spread operator didn't work for me. I think it's explained in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478289/react-hooks-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property

I didn't try it, but it looked like you use the spread operator within a spread operator within a spreadoperator. 
`const particleCopy = {
  ...particle,
  props: {
    ...particle.props,
    style: {
      ...particle.props.style,
      top: top + 'px'
    }
  }
}
setParticle(particleCopy);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could use this function to do what I was trying to get .map to do:

```
function replaceItemAtIndex(arr, index, newValue) {  return [...arr.slice(0, index), newValue, ...arr.slice(index + 1)]; }
```

The .slice methods seem to create a new array, which satisfies javascript in a way that .map doesn't.