# Is it a good pattern to save react element in the useState for good perfomance?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

We thing that it will take good perfomance. Elems will't rerender.

```js
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(() => [<Counter key={0} i={0} />]);
  const onClick = () => {
    setItems([...items, <Counter key={items.length} i={items.length} />]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={onClick}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {items}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Counter({ i }) {
  console.log(`render ${i}`);

  return <h2>{i}</h2>;
}
```

For better understanding I make an example in the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-austin-qbtpm

Comment: No, React is data driven, Elements are not meant to be saved like that.

Comment: Yep, generally not a good idea to store jsx in the state. Here's a thread for you to read more about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875226/9430279

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add element to a state React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875097/add-element-to-a-state-react)

Answer (score 1):

Is not a good idea to store jsx in the state like Shawn Yap said.
But also in general with javascript this is a bad practice.
In this case it is more complicated than needed.
A good idea is to keep data as simple and lightweight as it can be and then add to it when needed.
In this example theres a few improvements you can do

```
// You used both function App() & const onClick = () =>
// Best to choose one and stick with it. 
const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const onClick = () => {
    setItems([
      ...items,
      items.length
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={onClick}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      // Instead use a map to render items, you also don't need another function for this
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        console.log("rendered item with index: ", index)
        return <h2 key={index}>{index}</h2>
      })}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also never store the key of an item, the key of an item with be based off the index. Although they may look the same if you delete an item in your example and then add a new item you will have an error.
`[1, 3, 3]` would have cased it to error out for you. `[1, 3, 3]` using the index of the array as the key will not error out.

Hope that helps and happy coding :)

Comment: I think OP tried to prevent re rendering all items when just one was added and although storing the jsx in state isn't the way to do it your answer doesn't show how either. I guess OP was looking for pure component and the useCallback/useMemo hooks.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent renders you can use pure component or use React.memo and make sure you never pass a new reference as prop by using useCallback or useMemo. Here is an example:

```js
const id = (i => () => ++i)(0);
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  const addCounter = React.useCallback(
    () =>
      setItems(items =>
        items.concat({
          id: id(),
          count: 0,
        })
      ),
    []
  );
  const add = React.useCallback(
    id =>
      setItems(items =>
        items.map(item =>
          item.id === id
            ? { ...item, count: item.count + 1 }
            : item
        )
      ),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addCounter}>Add counter</button>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Counter item={item} key={item.id} add={add} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const Counter = React.memo(function Counter({ item, add }) {
  console.log(`render ${item.id}`);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => add(item.id)}>
      {item.count}
    </button>
  );
});


//render app
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```