# intercommunication between pair of elements created in array of React.createElement

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have 2 react elements: **componentSender** and **componentReceiver**. That need to be generated in a loop N times.

The special thing they have is that every time someone click in one **componentSender**, a prop will change in the respective **componentReceiver**.

This pair of components could be as simple as:

```
function ComponentReceiver(props) {
  return (
    <div>{`Listening to "Sender ${props.indexVar}" and it last received: ${props.showVar}`}</div>
  );
}

function ComponentSender(props) {
  return (
    <input type="button" onClick={() => {props.onChangeValue(props.indexVar);}}
      value={`SENDER for ${props.indexVar}> `}
    />
  );
}
```

I am using React.createElement in a loop and creating the pairs, you can see it here:

https://codepen.io/danieljaguiar/pen/bGVJbGw?editors=1111

The big problem in my demo is that, when I change the state in the parent (APP), the child components don't re-render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix up few things:

- [try not to store jsx in state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875097/add-element-to-a-state-react/47875226#47875226). Iterate and render directly in render.
- in `handleChangeValue` function, the show state reference is not changed at all and hence the component is not re-rendered. Make sure to take a copy of `show` (use spread operator) and then update state.
- remove unnecessary code in useEffect and

[Working & simplified copy of your code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/re-rendering-issue-fix-ehwnk?file=/src/App.js) in the codesandbox

**Code Snippet with fixes**

```js
function ComponentReceiver(props) {
  return (
    <div>{`Listening to "Sender ${props.indexVar}" and I received: ${
      props.showVar
    }`}</div>
  );
}

function ComponentSender(props) {
  return (
    <input
      type="button"
      onClick={() => {
        props.onChangeValue(props.indexVar);
      }}
      value={`SENDER for ${props.indexVar} ----------------------> `}
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [show, SetShow] = React.useState([]);
  const [pageElements, setPageElements] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChangeValue = val => {
    const updatedShow = [...show];
    updatedShow[val] = !updatedShow[val];
    SetShow(updatedShow);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let index = 0;
    let elements = [];

    while (index < 5) {
      show[index] = true;
      SetShow([...show]);

      elements.push(
        <div key={index} style={{ display: "flex", margin: "20px" }}>
          <ComponentSender
            key={index + "s"}
            indexVar={index}
            onChangeValue={handleChangeValue}
          />
          <ComponentReceiver
            key={index + "R"}
            indexVar={index}
            showVar={show[index]}
          />
        </div>
      );

      index++;
      SetShow([...show]);
    }
    setPageElements(elements);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {[...Array(5).keys()].map((_, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} style={{ display: "flex", margin: "20px" }}>
            <ComponentSender
              key={index + "s"}
              indexVar={index}
              onChangeValue={handleChangeValue}
            />
            <ComponentReceiver
              key={index + "R"}
              indexVar={index}
              showVar={show[index]}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```