# Adding multiple elements to state with map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have 2 buttons, `Single Component` and `Multiple Component`.

When I click on `Multiple Component`, I expect it to add 3 components, but it adds only 1.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";

function App() {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {});

  const newArray = [1, 2, 3];

  const Test = observer(() => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
    );
  });

  const Test2 = observer(() => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Test2</p>
      </div>
    );
  });

  const Test3 = observer(() => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Test3</p>
      </div>
    );
  });

  async function MultipleComponent() {
    newArray.map(async (x) => {
      if (x === 1) {
        await setComponent([...component, Test]);
      } else if (x === 2) {
        await setComponent([...component, Test2]);
      } else {
        await setComponent([...component, Test3]);
      }
      console.log(x);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {component.map((Input, index) => (
        <Input components={component} key={index} />
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => setComponent([...component, Test])}>
        Single Component
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => MultipleComponent()}>Multiple Component</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

codensadbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useeffect-forked-edmgb5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in using `await` on `setState`, nowhere the docs say it is a good idea.
On the other hand you need to use version of `setState` which accepts an *updater function*, there  you can get previous state.

```
setComponent(ps=>[...ps, Test2])
```

Also, I don't have link to official docs, but I am not sure [storing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62912502/can-i-put-react-component-inside-state) components inside state is good idea either. You could store some identifier in state which indicates which component it is and then render that one when time comes. Here is what I mean by this:

```
let Test1 = (props) => {
  return <div>1</div>;
};

let Test2 = (props) => {
  return <div>2</div>;
};

let GeneralComponent = (props) => {
  if (props.comp === '1') return <Test1 />;
  if (props.comp === '2') return <Test2 />;
  return null;
};

export default function App() {
  let [comp, setComp] = React.useState('1');
  return (
    <div onClick={() => setComp(comp === '1' ? '2' : '1')}>
      <GeneralComponent comp={comp} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `GeneralComp` accepts an identifier of which component to render, which is stored in state in parent.

Comment: thanks for your comment and answer, but I'm not very familiar with reactjs so I couldn't understand your suggestion. ( You could store some identifier in state which indicates which component it is and then render that one when time comes) Could you please give some more detailed information or an example?

Comment: @user19639519 I don't know how you were using the passed component, but check updated answer, there is example which shows that `GeneralComponent` can decide what to render without accepting say `<Test1/>` as prop