# How to return a complex <div></div> directly from state and pass it to child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need want to pass a big chunk of text to my child component from my parent.
I have a  Class component with state where i want to pass a text to modal. Issue is that, it is quite big chunk of text.

My state

```
state={
 iten:[
 {
  id: 1,
  header: 'header text',
  bigChunkForModal:
   <div>
    <p>pargaraph text1</P
     <ul><li> List item 1</li></ul>
    <p>pargaraph text2</P
     <ul><li> List item 2</li></ul>
    <p>pargaraph text3</P
     <ul><li> List item 3</li></ul>
   </div>,
   modalHeader: 'Modal header
   },
  ],
}:
```

I want all this to move from my state to my modal

```
{item.map((item) => {
 return(
  <Modal
    show={showModal === item.id}
    classModal={'btn-offer'}
    modalId={item.id}
    modalHeader={item.modalHeader}
    modalText={item.bigChunkForModal}
    close={() => this.closeModal()}
  />
 );
}
```

And finaly my modal. I have 3 buttons that should display 3 modals. This part is working. good

```
const ModalOverlay = ({
  className,
  modalHeader,
  show,
  modalId,
  modalText,
  classModal,
  close,
}) => {
  const content = (
    <div
      className={`Modal__Container ${className}`}
      style={{
        display: show ? 'inline' : 'none',
      }}>
      <div key={modalId} className={`Modal__Content ${className}`}>
        <h2>{modalHeader}</h2>
        <div>{modalText}</div>
        <button className={`btn ${classModal}`} onClick={close}>
          Zamknij
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    content,
    document.getElementById('modal-portal')
  );
};
```

Only thing that i need to work how to do is that state part. Any sugestions?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be trying to store JSX (or HTML) in the state.  Instead, store the data needed to render the content of the modal.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875235/3084820

Comment: thanks for that. WIll check this topic

Answer (score 1):

You approach though working but you can structure the component API a bit differently to make it more obvious.

```
<Modal show = {show} header="Demo Modal" onClose={}>
   <div>This will be available in the modal component as props.childrent {text}</div>
</Modal>
```

The modal buttons will be abstracted in the Modal component. By doing thhis you can pass the modal content as part of the modal definition and inside Modal component you can grab the children props and render at the appropriate place.  I have given the placeholders only.  {} values can be dynamic.

NOTE:  If you can put your  current MVP working code in a jsbin/codepen, I can update the modified structure to avoid state populated with HTML's.