# Browser Not showing Input Value when changing it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I have an example of how the value of the Input element will change but the browser won't show the current value, you can check in the DevTools of the browser that the value is changed.

I'm wondering why it's not showing the actual value of the Input element.

```
import { useState } from "react"


export default()=>{
const [input,setinput]=useState(<></>)

const AddInput=(name)=>{
  setinput(<input type='text' defaultValue={name} />)
}
return <>
{input}
<button onClick={()=>{AddInput('name1')}}>Add input with Name1</button>
<button onClick={()=>{AddInput('name2')}}>Add input with Name2</button>
</>
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to store the JSX itself in the state [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875097/add-element-to-a-state-react) ....

Answer (score 1):

You are actually setting its default value and not the actual value thats why it is not getting updated

Make this change

```
setinput(<input type="text" value={name} />);
```

Entire code

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default () => {
  const [input, setinput] = useState(<></>);

  const AddInput = (name) => {
    setinput(<input type="text" value={name} />);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {input}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          AddInput("name1");
        }}
      >
        Add input with Name1
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          AddInput("name2");
        }}
      >
        Add input with Name2
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: This will cause an warning saying it will render a read-only field, if you want to change the value this is not the way to do it.

Comment: RubenSmn is right, you can't change the value

Comment: Yes correct, but again adding onChange would solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is not a controlled input. It only has a `defaultValue` which is the reason it shows `value` prop. If you remove the `defaultValue` from the input you will see that there is no `value` at all on the input.

To see the `value` prop change you need a controlled input, you can do this like so

```js
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("Your default value");

const AddInput=(name)=>{
  setinput(<input type='text' value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)} />)
}
```

The [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) have great documentation on how controlled inputs work.