# How can I prevent react state from being re rendered when other state changes

Tags: reactjs, state, react-state-management, rerender

So I have reacted react state and added event listener on change but when i select an image and then complete other forms the image will be re rendered causing performance issues.

There are some images to explain:

[from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FeVh.png)

[the rerendering problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvTAy.png)

React state initialization:

```
const [lesson_name, setLessonName] = useState("");
const [lesson_description, setLessonDescription] = useState("");
const [lessson_image, setLessonImage] = useState(null);
const [section_name, setSectionName] = useState("");
const [section_description, setSectionDescription] = useState("");
const [video_1, setVideo1] = useState(null);
const [section_image_1, setSectionImage1] = useState(null);
const [section_image_2, setSectionImage2] = useState(null);
const [section_image_3, setSectionImage3] = useState(null);
const [section_code1, setSectionCode1] = useState("");
const [section_code2, setSectionCode2] = useState("");
const [section_code3, setSectionCode3] = useState("");
const [section_code4, setSectionCode4] = useState("");
```

On change listener

```
<input
   className="w-full h-[50px] border border-gray-300 rounded-md p-2"
   type="text"
   id="lessonTitle"
   // prevent rerendering

   onChange={(e) => setLessonName(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Is there any method that i can use to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React has **useMemo** to provide more performant for heavy calculations or components. If you can wrap the div that you want to rerender when the data on dependencies are changed, it doesn't rerender continentally when any state data is changed.

Of course, this example provides that all images will rerender when you change the data like section_image_1, section_image_2 or section_image_3

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [lesson_name, setLessonName] = useState("");
  const [lesson_description, setLessonDescription] = useState("");
  const [lessson_image, setLessonImage] = useState(null);
  const [section_name, setSectionName] = useState("");
  const [section_description, setSectionDescription] = useState("");
  const [video_1, setVideo1] = useState(null);
  const [section_image_1, setSectionImage1] = useState(null);
  const [section_image_2, setSectionImage2] = useState(null);
  const [section_image_3, setSectionImage3] = useState(null);
  const [section_code1, setSectionCode1] = useState("");
  const [section_code2, setSectionCode2] = useState("");
  const [section_code3, setSectionCode3] = useState("");
  const [section_code4, setSectionCode4] = useState("");

  const memorizedImages = useMemo(
    () => (
      <div>
        <img src={section_image_1} />
        <img src={section_image_2} />
        <img src={section_image_3} />
      </div>
    ),
    [section_image_1, section_image_2, section_image_3]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        className="w-full h-[50px] border border-gray-300 rounded-md p-2"
        type="text"
        id="lessonTitle"
        onChange={(e) => setLessonName(e.target.value)}
      />
      {memorizedImages}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should avoid to "store" elements in `useMemo`, see [element to a react state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875226)

Answer (score 1):

Using React Memo,

Create Image component:

```js
import { memo } from "react";

// memoized component
const Image = memo(({ src, alt }) => <img src={src} alt={alt} />);
```

and use it instead of `<img />`:

```js
<Image src={section_image_1} alt={'some text here'} />
```

Comment: It still re renders when the text input changes

Comment: Then it signals me about two problems you might be having:
1. You might be re-mounting the parent component. Be careful about the usage of key props. Also check if re-mounting occurs with `useEffect(()=>{console.log('remount')},[])`


2. You might be calling setSectionImage1 or fetching Images unnecessarily. Show more of your code.