# How to generate react components imperatively in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-dom

Let's say I have a button, when I click on this button a React component should be generated and injected into the target node:

```
const generateAndInjectMarkup = e => {
// define my node here lets say
const nodeToInject = <p> Hello </p>

// now how do I inject and render the markup in the target node? 
} 


<div>
 <button onClick={generateAndInjectMarkup}> generate </button>
 <div ref={container} id="target"></div> {/* this is where I want to inject the jsx I want to generate */}
</div>
```

How do I solve this problem? I'm working on a form generator, I saw at renderToString API given by React, but I'm unsure how to inject and render the markup I have generated.

Should I use a portal or createRoot?

Comment: The biggest missing piece of this question: How/from what should the markup be generated?

Comment: @AdamJenkins the markup could be generated based on the user's input from the dropdown, it could be an Input field, textarea, buttons, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not at all different than any other declarative react problem, you might be overthinking it

```
const generateStuff = () => {
   return /* some jsx */
}


const MyComponent = () => {
   const [generatedStuff,setGeneratedStuff] = useState(null)

   return (
     <div>
       <button onClick={() => setGeneratedStuff(generateStuff())}> generate </button>
       <div id="target">{generatedStuff}</div>
     </div>
   )

}
```

Comment: Is it alright to store jsx elements as a part of state? I saw this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875226/12079043 answer and got confused. I then looked at createRoot API which is solving the problem but wanted to know what are good practices when solving this kind of problem

Comment: You need not store the jsx element in state. You could just store the content/props needed to render the element in the state and use the state values as props for the imperatively generated element.

Comment: There’s absolutely no technical reason or even best practice not to store them in state. Store whatever you need to in state. If it were redux or something else, well, there might be a preference to store serializable things as state. But that’s also just a preference and not any sort of hard rule or gotcha

Comment: @AdamJenkins Thank you the approach you suggested is very simple, I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const generateAndInjectMarkup = () => {
  return <p> Hello </p>;
};

const MainComponent = () => {
  const [showMarkup, setShowMarkup] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setShowMarkup(true)}> generate </button>
      <div ref={container} id="target">
        {showMarkup ? generateAndInjectMarkup() : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This should do the work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).