# Function that uses useState always returns different value when nothing was changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have this React code (sorry if variable names are in Spanish) it creates a list of <tr> to use on a table i have in my html, every <tr> has some values and a button that should trigger the deletion of the row (that's handled by the "removerMaterialLista()" function). The thing is that every time i click on the button it gives me a different value for the useState the function splices and modifies (that would be "Materiales"). I seriously have no clue what's going on.

```jsx
const [Materiales, setMateriales] = useState([]);
const [ListaMateriales, setListaMateriales] = useState([]);

const agregarMaterialLista = () => {
  let listaHTML = [];
  let lista = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Materiales.length; i++) {
    listaHTML.push(ListaMateriales[i]);
  }
  listaHTML.push(
    <tr>
      <td>{NombreMaterial}</td>
      <td>{CostoMaterial}</td>
      <td>{StockMaterial}</td>
      <td>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="deleteMaterial"
          onClick={() => removerMaterialLista(listaHTML.length - 1)}
        >
          X
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>,
  );

  setListaMateriales(listaHTML);
  setMateriales(lista);
  setNombreMaterial("");
  setCostoMaterial("");
  setStockMaterial("");
};

const removerMaterialLista = (posicion) => {
  console.log(posicion);
  console.log([...Materiales]);
  let lista = [...Materiales];
  let listaHTML = [];
  lista.splice(posicion, 1);

  for (let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    listaHTML.push(
      <tr>
        <td>{lista[i].titulo}</td>
        <td>{lista[i].costo}</td>
        <td>{lista[i].stock}</td>
        <td>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="deleteMaterial"
            onClick={() => removerMaterialLista(i)}
          >
            X
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>,
    );
  }

  setListaMateriales(listaHTML);
  setMateriales(lista);
};
```

Here's what the output looks like when pressing from the top button to the last one: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RGEw.png). It seems to always be one element short

EDIT: I Solved it based on the answer of avoiding redundant states, now the html portion is calculated based on the 'Materiales' state that i have, resulting in it always having the latest version to work with.

```
    const agregarMaterialLista = () => {
    let lista = []
    for(let i = 0; i < Materiales.length; i++){
        lista.push(Materiales[i])
    }
    lista.push({titulo: NombreMaterial, costo: CostoMaterial, stock: StockMaterial})
    setMateriales(lista)
    
    setNombreMaterial("")
    setCostoMaterial("")
    setStockMaterial("")
}

const listaMaterialesHTML = () => {
    let html = []
    for(let i = 0; i < Materiales.length; i++){
        html.push(<tr><td>{Materiales[i].titulo}</td><td>{Materiales[i].costo}</td><td>{Materiales[i].stock}</td><td><button type ="button" class="deleteMaterial" onClick={() => removerMaterialLista(i)}>X</button></td></tr>)
    }
    return html
}

const removerMaterialLista = (posicion) => {
    let lista = [...Materiales]
    lista.splice(posicion, 1)
    setMateriales(lista)
}
```

Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: You should not store JSX elements in state. State is for data, not representation

Comment: `agregarMaterialLista` does `setMateriales([])` which is probably wrong.

Comment: @Phil Depending on what you are doing, putting elements in state is ok, so I would not generalise this. But yes, it's definitely not necessary here, the root of the problem is [keeping redundant values in multiple state](https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-redundant-state)

Comment: @Bergi I refer to the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875226/283366). Perhaps it's old advice but I still wouldn't put anything presentational in state; it just doesn't feel right

Comment: @Phil I agree it's still good advice, just never say never. I was thinking of a `<DialogContextProvider>` whose children could use something like `openDialog(<CustomDialogContent>…</CustomDialogContent>)` - the provider would have to store the `openDialog` argument in its state to render it.

Comment: @Bergi good call out, I didn't mean to sound so prescriptive