# Why is my state (array) reset each time the button is selected, instead of added to the array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

```
const FilterElement: FunctionComponent = ({ }) => {

    const [selectedProperty, setSelectedProperty] = useState<ReactNode>();
    const [type, setType] = useState<TypeName[]>([]);

    const handleType = (value: TypeName[]) => {
        const newValue = [...type as TypeName[], value] as TypeName[];
        setType(newValue);
    }

    const onChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        const { value } = event.target;
        setSelectedProperty(<FilterElementType handleType={handleType} />);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className='filter-element'>
                <select name='filter-property' onChange={onChange}>
                    <option value='type'>Type</option>
                </select>
                {selectedProperty}
            </div>
            {type ? <Container field={type} /> : null}
        </>
    );
}
```

```
interface IFilterElementTypeProps {
    handleType: (value: TypeName[]) => void;
}

const FilterElementType: FunctionComponent<IFilterElementTypeProps> = ({ handleType }) => {

    const onClick = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        const { value } = event.currentTarget;
        handleType([value as TypeName]);
    };

    const typeList = getTypes()
    .map(type =>
        <button className='type-button' value={type.name} onClick={onClick} key={uniqueId()}>
            <MoveImage type={type.name} />
        </button>
    );

    return (
        <div className='filter-element-type'>
            {typeList}
        </div>
    );
}

export default FilterElementType;
```

I'm trying to understand why, given the two components provided, each time an option is selected on the 'FilterElementType' component, the 'type' state on the 'FilterElement' is reset to the default state '[]'.

My understanding of the code is that each selection should be adding to the array, but instead it's being replaced. How would I alter this to make sure the array is modified (added to) instead of replaced?

I have tried countless modifications to adding to the state, but it seems no matter what, the component is re-rendered and the state is defaulted.

Comment: Why all the type casting? It appears to be completely unnecessary. You're also appending an array of `TypeName` which doesn't seem right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of unnecessary type casting and array wrapping going on here. I also [wouldn't recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875226/283366) storing elements in state.

I'd say your main problem is that this is fundamentally incorrect

> ```ts
> const newValue = [...type as TypeName[], value] as TypeName[];
> ```

Because `value` is itself an array, the result here would be something like `Array<TypeName | TypeName[]>` so it is being mis-cast.

---

First, if you're only expecting a single value in `onClick`, why wrap it in an array? Just send the value

```ts
interface IFilterElementTypeProps {
  handleType: (value: TypeName) => void;
}
```

and in your component...

```ts
const onClick = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  const { value } = event.currentTarget;
  handleType(value as TypeName); //  no array wrapper
};
```

Second, if you're modifying state based on the current value, use the [functional setter](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)

```ts
const handleType = (value: TypeName) => { //  no array here
  setType((prev) => [...prev, value]); //  functional setter, no casting
};
```

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot of clarification here. Some of that typecasting was certainly unnecessary, it was left-over from frustrated attempts at understanding what was going on.